# Addition of two continuous functions is continuous ($\epsilon-\delta$ approach)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_1,f_2:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ be continuous at $a \in \mathbb R^n$. Prove that 
$$ f_1+f_2$$
is continuous at $a$ by $\epsilon-\delta$ arguments. I know how to do this for $f_1*f_2$ but am confused for this particular statement/question.

Comment: HINT: Triangle Inequality.

Answer (score 4):

Knowing that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous at $a$ gives for any $\epsilon$ values $\delta_1,\delta_2$ such that for $\|x-a\|<\delta_1$ it is true that $\|f_1(x)-f_1(a)\|<\epsilon$ and for $\|x-a\|<\delta_2$ it is true that $\|f_2(x)-f_2(a)\|<\epsilon$.

It follows that for $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
2\epsilon& > \|f_1(x)-f_1(a)\|+\|f_2(x)-f_2(a)\|\\
& \ge \|f_1(x)-f_1(a)+f_2(x)-f_2(a)\|\quad \mathrm{(Triangle\ inequality)}\\
& = \|(f_1+f_2)(x)-(f_1+f_2)(a)\|
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$

if $\|x-a\|<\delta$.

So indeed, you can find $\delta$ satisfying the criterion for any value $2\epsilon$, and thus for any $\epsilon$, so $f_1+f_2$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: Maybe you could add $||(f_1+f_2)(x)-(f_1+f_2)(a)|| = ||(f_1(x)-f_1(a))+(f_2(x)-f_2(a))||$ as an intermediate step to show the use of the triangle inequality. (+1)

Comment: @sonystarmap: Done.